# Fetch is taking longer than usual

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I'm doing a simple fetch as follows

```
      useLayoutEffect(() => {
            var v1 = performance.now();
            fetch('https://example.com/api/')
           .then(result => {        
                  var v2 = performance.now();
                  console.log("total time taken for fetch = "+(v2-v1)+"milliseconds");
                  return result.json()
            })
           .then(data => {
                  var v3 = performance.now();
                  console.log("total time  taken = "+(v3-v1)+"milliseconds");
                  console.log(data.data);
           })
      },[])
```

[image: Fetch console.log]

In the server side, I included the server execution time which shows 0.00759 seconds to process the entire php script including the php query.

I have access the API directly via browser and it's extremely fast as well, almost instantly.

However when I use react/javascript, there is a huge delay sometimes up to 7-10 seconds.

I wish to know how I can find out where is the bottleneck for the lag/delay.

Comment: how big is your array?

Comment: Have you looked at the network panel in your browser dev tools? It generally breaks down the timing info for you, so you can see time spent for things like "request sent," "waiting," "content download," etc. That might be helpful.

Comment: the array is very small with about 10+ items. Timeline on safari shows 2-3 minutes under Network Request. 
Good to note that if I access the API directly via browser, is blazingly fast.